# gridview with cached paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, odbc

Would it be possible to implement paging in a Gridview using a cached SqlDataSource? I want to run the query once, results get stored in the cache and then I can just go through Gridview pages and load the cached result as I change pages, without rerunning the query? I know it is more efficient to just grab only records I need for the current page but since I will have an option to export to Excel on the page, I want everything grabbed in one go.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Results" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSorting="Submit_Query" CellPadding="5" Class="highlightable"
            OnRowDataBound="Results_RowDataBound" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100" EmptyDataText="No Data Found">
</asp:GridView>
```

The SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" EnableCaching="true"  ></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Function to run on page change

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
         {
          Results.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
          //Submit_Query();  //???
        }
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: Sounds like an easy task if you switch to the `ObjectDataSource`. If there's no reason to stick with the sql data source, you have a way to follow.

Comment: From my own experience, and what I've read from a number of people online, caching with the `ObjectDataSource` is not as simple as one might hope. So much so that they usually look elsewhere.

Comment: Seems like you should set DataSourceMode=DataSet [Help about](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource(v=vs.110).aspx) Paging
Not currently supported by the SqlDataSource, however some data-bound controls, such as GridView, support paging when you set the DataSourceMode property to the DataSet value.